# How can I calculate magnetic flux density/field strength with given Force on a current carrying wire, Current and length of wire, using $F=BIL$ eq?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics

For my student experiment we had measured the force that magnets have on an electromagnetic copper wire with the length of 20 cm, as the current increases, the magnets push down the copper wire more on the weigh which gives the force. I am trying to calculate the magnetic flux density but using formulas decreases the strength as voltage increases so I am now stuck. The current was 1.85 amps at 2 V, copper wire length 20 cm, force of 0.00277 N/kg. I have tried rearranging the formula of $F=BIL$ to $B=F/IL$ but as said the strength is decreasing when the current increases which should not be happening. Please help!!!!

Comment: What does the force when you increase the current?

Comment: the force increases as the current increases but not sure how to calculate the magnetic field with the values I have collected

Comment: If both force and current increase your formula for B does not mean that B decreases when current increases.

Comment: so the practical was adding horseshoe magnets ontop of a current carrying wire that is perpendicular to the other forces from the horseshoe magnet, i figured by adding more magnets would change the length of wire being effected so i did the calculations and now my data represents that as more magnets are added the magnetic flux density (B) decreases and as current increases (B) decreases so both are going down hahah im not sure about the science behind it, please explain it

Comment: wait no the magnetic flux stays the same as the voltage increases but decreases as more magnets are added.